# Query MySQL DB for new entry and play sound on HTML

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, audio, playback

I have a script which loops every 2 seconds and I am looking to make it play a sound on the webpage when it detects a new entry in my database.

I have the part of the script which will play the sound, but do not have the part which checks the database. I have looked all over the internet for something or someone that has got this to work but I haven't found anything which is at all helpful.

All I need is for someone to help me write the script which checks the DB every x seconds and plays a sound for users to hear.

I would appreciate any help as I am lost at this point.

```
<script>
setInterval (function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "test2.php",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data) {
                var audio = new Audio('sounds/alert.mp3');
                audio.play();
            }
        }
    });
}, 2000);
</script>



------- test2.php -------
$sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS NumberOfRows FROM death_logs WHERE combat_log=1";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);

if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
        $oldRows = $row1["NumberOfRows"];
    }
}


sleep(1);


$sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS NumberOfRows FROM death_logs WHERE combat_log=1";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
        $newRows = $row2["NumberOfRows"];
    }
}


if ($oldRows < $newRows) {
    //echo "Old Rows (".$oldRows.") - New Rows (".$newRows.")";
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Thank you,
Josh L.

Comment: One basic approach would be polling the server using AJAX

Comment: Thanks. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Well where are you stuck exactly? You don't know how to use AJAX? Or how to write the database query? Or what? If you don't know anything about these technologies then you need to take some introductory tutorials etc and make some attempt at it. On Stackoverflow we're happy to help you with specific issues but we can't teach you the fundamentals or provide ready-made designs and solutions.

Comment: I have attempted it, as you can see from my code linked within the post. What I have created, in theory, should work so I am confused as to why it does not. If I could get a pointer as to why it may not work then I can try fix it from there.

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**_. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).. Linking to code on an external site isn't acceptable by SO's community rules unfortunately. We aren't going to click on that.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting if you need assistance with including your code into your question correctly. Thanks.

Comment: I have stated the desired behaviour and the specific problem - It doesn't return true, when it should. The code has been added in its shortest form, in the question

Comment: Thanks. Your code doesn't make much sense. You run a query, wait one second and then run the exact same query again. The chances of someone adding a new row in that gap is tiny. What your script really needs to do is store the last time it was executed (maybe in the Session), and then when it's called, query the database for all rows added since the last time it was executed. (This relies of course on you having a "date created" datetime/timestamp column in your database table, which stores the precise date and time the row was added).

Comment: P.S. As an aside, if you really do run this every 2 seconds, then it will add some load to your database and server. Its processing capacity is not infinite, so if a lot of users will be doing this simultaneously, you can expect it to impact performance significantly. It's unclear what your usage scenario would be exactly, so just mentioning it as something to bear in mind.